# Printing hash values

Tags: perl, hash, key-value

I have a set of hash values which are arrays with same number of elements. They are printing below each other, but I want to print them next to each other.

In the output below, the columns starting with clakin_p, clkin_N and phy2clb_scan_out are different arrays which are diff values of hash and they are supposed to be next to each other.

```
for ( my $m = 0; $m <= ($#pin_names); $m++ ) {
    for ( my $n = 0; $n <= ($#output); $n++ ) {
        if ( $pin_names[$m] eq $output[$n] ) {
            print "$hash{$n}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Current output :-

```
    clkin_P
      1
      1
   clkin_N
      0
      0
   phy2clb_scan_out
      H
      H
```

Comment: Have you tried any other techniques?

Comment: Can you suggest something based on the above code where I can change something?

Comment: Well, you're currently printing `$hash{$n}` and then a line break. If you want the values to print next to each other, don't use a line break.

Comment: I want to put such logic which will print all the values of the hash next to each other like columns. Even after removing last it is doing the same thing.

Comment: Please edit your post to add more of your code (i.e. where are the headers 'clkin_P', 'clkin_N', etc., coming from?), and the attempt you have made to change the output.

Comment: Hash values contains arrays of fixed lengths and they are getting printed. Now I want them to print next to each other.

Comment: Right. You need to edit your post to show where the headers 'clkin_P', 'clkin_N', etc. are coming from, and show your desired output. See [how to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `print "$hash{$n}\n";` includes a newline character at the end (`\n`).  This causes each hash value to be printed on a separate line.  Simply remove the newline.

Also, traditional `for` loops where you keep track of the iterator are rarely needed in Perl and are a potential source of mistakes in your code.  Much better would be this:

```
foreach my $pin (@pin_names) {
    foreach my $out (@output) {
        if ( $pin eq $out ) {
            print "$hash{$n} ";
        }
    }
}
```